# Как определить наличие коллекции в базе?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Такой вопрос: 
Как наиболее корректно проверить коллекция пуста или нет?
(Cуществует ли там хоть одна запись или нет или создана коллекция или нет.)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Прововал реализации что то наподобие этой 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но пока безрезультатно.
Есть идеи почему не работают подобные варианты?
Версия MongoDb: 4.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно что-то такое сделать..

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const url = 'mongodb+srv://..........';
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });

client.connect(async(err) => {
  const db = await client.db("nameCollection");
  const list = await db.listCollections();// Получаем информацию, т. е. имя и параметры, о коллекциях в базе данных.

  await list.forEach(async(doc) => {
    const count = await db.collection(doc.name).countDocuments();//Количество документов в коллекции
    console.log(count);
  });
  
  client.close();
});
```